# Is there any way to verify the integrity of an xz archive without decompressing the entire archive?

Tags: tar, compression, archive, integrity, xz

Can I check the integrity of the archive without decompressing it as the archive is 64GB. It is a backup of my old laptop and before i format my old laptop I wanted to verify the backup but it will take too long to decompress and verify. So is there a faster way to do so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure, you can do:

```
xz -t backup.xz
```

A blank result is no errors. If you want more details you can do:

```
xz -tvv backup.xz
```